# pyspark : how to configure StopWordsRemover with french language on spark 1.6.3

Tags: pyspark, stop-words

I would like to know how to configure stopwordsremover with french language in spark 1.6.3.

I'm currently using pyspark.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

Comment: [`pyspark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover) has a parameter `stopWords` which you can use to specify your own list. You can get a list of French stop words using `StopWordsRemover.loadDefaultStopWords('french')` but this doesn't seem like it's available for v1.6.3 based on the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/ml-features.html#stopwordsremover).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [nltk](https://www.nltk.org/) package

I use it for portuguese words:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StopWordsRemover
import nltk
nltk.download("stopwords")

...

stopwordList = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('portuguese')
remover = StopWordsRemover(inputCol=tokenizer.getOutputCol(), outputCol="stopWordsRem", stopWords=stopwordList)
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Based on Python Spark 1.6.3 [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover), pyspark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover does not have a language parameter. However you can always provide your own list of stopwords via the "stopWords" parameter.